# Find if there are duplicated values across each row

Tags: python, pandas

For some reason, I cant think of the best solution for this problem. I am looking for a solution that does not involve iterating.

Lets say we have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3,5,6,2,3],[3,5,7,3,5],[5,5,3,5,4],[2,3,4,5,6]])

    0   1   2   3   4
0   3   5   6   2   3
1   3   5   7   3   5
2   5   5   3   5   4
3   2   3   4   5   6
```

What would be the best way to find the rows with no duplicate numbers. Only the last row satisfies the requirement. I have come up with the solution below, but I feel like I am missing a more obvious answer.

```
df.rank(axis=1,method='dense').eq(len(df.columns)).any(axis=1)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Is there a way to find duplicates across rows a better way?

As a bonus, what would be the best way to make a list that shows the numbers that were duplicated.

My solution works, but I feel like I am forgetting a much better way:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().loc[x.value_counts().gt(1)].index.tolist(),axis=1)

    0   1   2   3   4   dups
0   3   5   6   2   3   [3]
1   3   5   7   3   5   [3, 5]
2   5   5   3   5   4   [5]
3   2   3   4   5   6   []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) on axis=1 to count the unique values per row and compare to width of the DataFrame:

```
df.nunique(axis=1).eq(df.shape[1])
```

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

---

Edit to include an answer to the "bonus" question added after my initial answer via [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
df.apply(lambda s: s[s.duplicated()].unique(), axis=1)
```

`df`:

```
0       [3]
1    [3, 5]
2       [5]
3        []
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Let us try numpy way

```
def row_dup(a):
         v, c = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
         return list(v[np.where(c > 1)])
     
df.apply(row_dup,1)
Out[222]: 
0       [3]
1    [3, 5]
2       [5]
3        []
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

@Henry's answer is already good, but for the "bonus" question:

```py
df["dups"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: (v := x.value_counts())[v > 1].index.tolist(), 1
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   0  1  2  3  4    dups
0  3  5  6  2  3     [3]
1  3  5  7  3  5  [3, 5]
2  5  5  3  5  4     [5]
3  2  3  4  5  6      []
```